# Problem to trim data with single quotes into a table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table where one of it's fields follow this format:

**Table Foo**

```
info
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
['email', 'phone', 'reviews', 'manual_offline', 'jumio', 'government_id']
['email', 'phone']
['email', 'phone', 'reviews', 'offline_government_id', 'selfie', 'government_id', 'identity_manual']
...
```

In order to separate each value from table `Foo` into another table to normalize the model, I want to separate each string from the array on each row on `info` field and insert it into a different table.

To separate the values, I tried executing this `select` but I figured out single quotes (`'`) on the array are giving some problems because I can't use them on the `trim` first parameter as postgresql will think I'm separating strings:

```
select distinct (trim('['']' FROM REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(info, ','))) from ImportH;
```

In spite that I executed the `select` and got the values separated, but some of them contain a single quote at the beginning.

output example I'm getting:

`'phone
facebook
'email
...`

How can I do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your splitter is really `', '`.  So try this:

```
select distinct (trim('['']' FROM REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(info, ''', ''')))
from ImportH;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trim, you can use replace, which replaces the single quote.

```
select replace(column_name, '''', '') from ImportH;
```

But if you could explain exact result, can help more on that